# Extending OpenFileDialog to select folder and file simultaneously

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

What I am trying to achieve is to select multiple folders and files **simultaneously**  from the OpenFileDialog.
The suggested solution of setting:

```
OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
OpenFileDialog.ValidateNames = false;
OpenFileDialog.CheckFileExists = false;
OpenFileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
OpenFileDialog.FileName = "Dummy";
OpenFileDialog.Filter = string.Empty;
```

This setting fails for the use case when the user selects a folder and a file **simultaneously**.

I am looking for a solution via which I can close the dialog when the user presses the **open** button and get the path for the selected file(s) and folder(s).

[image]